# First code clarification for error rectification?

Tags: python

I am learning python as 'new comer in coding'. I was writing a code and got a following error. Can someone please rectify why I have following with the code. Thank you

```
def mean(value):
    if type(value) == dict:
        the_mean=(sum(value.values()) / len(value))
        else:
            the_mean = sum(value) / len(value)
    
        return the_mean

student_grades={"Marry":2,"Jim":3,"Sam":5}

print(mean(student_grades))
print(type(mean),type(sum))
```

---

The error is on line 4

Comment: Hi! Can you give us a bit more detail about the error? What's the error message your seeing?

Comment: can you please share the stack trace? Also can you please correct the indentation in above code?

Comment: I suspect the incorrect indentation *is* the error.

Comment: It is a syntax error, right? (You did not say, and you should have.) If so, it is because `else` should line up with `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove 1 indentation from the line : a python `if` statement is written :

```
def foo():
    if condition:
        ...
    else:
        ...
    return
```